# A better way to replace many if conditions

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm pretty new with Java.

I would like to be advised if there is an intelligent way to replace many many
if statement.

**The problem:**
Let's say i have a validator class that check tags in incoming message. Each tag can be mandatory or not for my application.

Instead of using many if statements :

```
if (isExistTag1)
else if (isExistTag2)
else if (isExistTag3)
.
.
.
else if (isExistTagN)
```

what can be an improved way?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried switch case

Comment: Are all those `if` blocks doing the same things? Similar things?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: This question has already been posted many times. I see it at least twice per week.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: If one of your conditionals is `true` are the rest **always** `false`?

Comment: no. if one of the conditions if flase, i will send an error and drop the incoming message.

Comment: Try validTags or Switch cases

Answer (score 3):

One out of many possibilities would be to use a List:

```
private List<String> validTags = Arrays.asList(
    tag1, //
    tag2, //
    tag3);

public boolean isTagValid(String tag) {
    return validTags.contains(tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If one of your conditionals is `true` and the rest are **always** `false`, you could use either an array or `ArrayList` of `Runnable`s.  Essentially, you would have all of the logic that lives inside each conditional inside of its own method that is defined inside of either the array or `ArrayList`.  Then you would just need to translate your `boolean` conditional values into an `int` range starting at 0.  At that point you could just reference the `ArrayList` like so:

```
List<Runnable> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
conditions.add(new Runnable()->{/*code to execute if condition 0 is true*/});
conditions.add(new Runnable()->{/*code to execute if condition n is true*/});


conditions.get(translatedBoolean).run();
```

This is a bit more elegant of an approach and will eliminate the needless processing time if only your last conditional is `true`

There are also other functional interfaces that Java provides if you need to return a value or pass parameters.

Comment: each tag can be true or false. when i got the first false i will drop the incoming message

Comment: Can you provide some more information on how to use this list please? What is translated boolean?